# How to install forked version of a library in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

I found a React JS library called [React Pacomo](https://github.com/gadventures/react-pacomo). Since the original package is no longer maintained, I decided to use my own forked version as the version I'd like to use in my project. However, the library is not compiling (or building?) correctly.

When I use the original library, I install it in my `package.json` like this:

```
"react-pacomo": "0.5.1",
```

And when I check `node_modules/react-pacomo`, I see the library has been built correctly because it has the `lib` folder inside it:

> $ ls node_modules/react-pacomo
> README.md    **lib**          package.json test.js

Now when I try to install my forked version, my `package.json` looks like this:

```
"@myname/react-pacomo": "git+ssh://git@github.com/myname/react-pacomo.git#0.5.1",
```

However, when I run `npm install`, the library doesn't compile properly, and this is the output of `ls node_modules/@myname/react-pacomo`

> $ ls node_modules/react-pacomo
> README.md package.json test.js

As you can see, no `lib` folder. Does anyone know why this could be?

Comment: Have you tried to run `yarn build` or `npm build` on the local fork to make sure it compiles locally properly?

Comment: I can clone my fork, and run `npm install` inside it, and it installs everything properly, yes

Comment: Nothing happens when I do `npm build` because the only scrips available are compile, prepublish, test and prepare and they all basically do `babel --presets es2015,stage-0 -d lib/ src/`

Comment: It's odd that it's not working during the `npm install` in the bigger project

Answer (score 0):

If you download the zip at that release it doesn't contain a lib folder either. I think that is being generated when the package is published to NPM.

https://github.com/gadventures/react-pacomo/releases